# error with the update of the eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, error-handling

i face  this problem with the updating plz help

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.jar.
Read timed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your proxy settings (using - Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections

In case you are directly connected to Internet then select direct other wise provide appropriate information for HTTP proxy (if you are behind proxy)

If correct settings in place then it should solve the issue.

Comment: i fix this error  step 1 go to  instal new software  step 2 delete **http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins** step 3 reinstall  it by clicking add than update any package you want

Comment: @jiji Feel free to post this as an answer, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

i fix this error step 1 go to instal new software step 2 delete **dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins** step 3 reinstall it by clicking add than update any package you want